# The not operator(!) is not working as expected in Octave. What could be the reason?

Tags: octave

In the following octave code, the condition in the while statement is not being evaluated as expected.
The condition in the while statement is always evaluating as "TRUE" even if the value of "stop_training" is being printed as the number 0.

What could be wrong with the statement?

```
stop_training = 0;
C = 1;
while (! stop_training)    %NOT operator is not working

  C = input("Enter the value for C:");
  if(length(C)==0) 
    C=1;
  endif

  fprintf("Using C = %d\n", C);
  A = C+1;

  stop_training = yes_or_no("continue to train the model?");
  fprintf("you chose:  %d\n", stop_training);

  pause;
endwhile
```

Comment: `!0` is true though...

Comment: "Continue to train the model?" > "Yes." > `stop_training` should be `0`, but it's actually `1` when I say `Yes`. You just switched the meanings. Can't reproduce the "error" if I pay attention to that.

Comment: This code works fine except the logic error that HansHirse pointed

Comment: just pointing out that the `!` operator has an entirely different meaning in matlab, therefore the matlab tag is inappropriate / misleading.

Comment: Thanks, I will remove the matlab tag.

Comment: Thanks HansHirse! It is a silly mistake but difficult to debug if we don`t take a break. Can you post that as an Answer so that I can mark it as an answer. I would probably see this as a logical mistake and an eye opener for others (hopefully).